# What data structure maintains insertion order, allows random access, and doesn't allow duplicates?

Tags: java, list, data-structures, set

I'm trying to implement a data structure that takes unique strings and stores them. I have to be able to delete and edit said strings.

I was originally thinking of using an Arraylist but the problem is every string has to be unique, so every single time a new string is added I would have to iterate through the list to check if it exists.

I then looked at LinkedHashSet which would make all item unique as no duplicates are allowed and it maintains insertion order, but it doesn't allow random access to edit strings. I could remove said strings and add the new edited string but that would change the order.

With the requirements I have, what data structure would be the best to implement in java?

Comment: Presumably, when you say "edit strings", you mean replace strings in the insertion order?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Yes exactly, I'm not sure if there's really a data structure that can do all 3, feels like I would need a list linkedhashset

Comment: You might consider writing your own class. Perhaps it could have an array list, and check for duplicates using a hash set. But, I wonder if there could be an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) here.

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer I think you're right, never heard of an "XY Problem" as I am relatively new to coding for clients. I think I'll reach out to see what he wants to achieve. Thank you.